# want one of the parameter to be a variable in my data when creating a function

Tags: r

My code is:

```
SMD.dicho <- function(data,c){
  a <- nrow(subset(data,c==1 & treat==1))
  b <- nrow(subset(data,c==0 & treat==1))
  c <- nrow(subset(data,c==1 & treat==0))
  d <- nrow(subset(data,c==0 & treat==0))
  pt <- a/(a+b)
  pc <- c/(c+d)
 return (pt-pc)/((pt*(1-pt)+pc*(1-pc))/2)^{0.5}
}

SMD.dicho(brain,sex)
```

brain is my dataset, c is one of the variables in my dataset, for example, a variable called `sex` in my dataset to indicate if this person is a man.however when I run my code, it shows

> Error in factor(c): object 'sex' not found

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass unquoted variable to the function, it would require non-standard evaluation which might complicate things and can be confusing in the beginning. Without changing much of your current approach, pass the column name as character and get the counts.

```
SMD.dicho <- function(data, col) {
   a <- sum(data[[col]] == 1 & data[["treat"]] == 1)
   b <- sum(data[[col]] == 0 & data[["treat"]] == 1)
   c <- sum(data[[col]] == 1 & data[["treat"]] == 0)
   d <- sum(data[[col]] == 0 & data[["treat"]] == 0)
   pt <- a/(a+b)
   pc <- c/(c+d)
   return (pt-pc)/((pt*(1-pt)+pc*(1-pc))/2)^{0.5}
}

SMD.dicho(brain,"sex")
```